# There are [community-standards] here?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

The [community-standards](/questions/tagged/community-standards) (30 questions, no tag wiki) tag here on Meta Stack Exchange seems unclear. It seems to imply some sort of social standard or community consensus is happening or being requested, but that's not really clear or helpful. We have several more specific tags related to rules of conduct and behavior that more specifically identify the problematic or potentially problematic conduct issue and that should be used instead.

- Questions about how to interpret, enforce, or adjudicate the Code of Conduct should be tagged [code-of-conduct](/questions/tagged/code-of-conduct).
- Questions about the now-obsolete Be Nice Policy should be tagged [be-nice-policy](/questions/tagged/be-nice-policy).
- Questions about the acceptability or unacceptability of certain social behaviors, unconnected with any specific policy, should be tagged [behavior](/questions/tagged/behavior).
- Questions about the boundaries of specific kinds of unacceptable or potentially problematic behavior should be tagged with the applicable behavior, such as [spam](/questions/tagged/spam), [abuse](/questions/tagged/abuse), [serial-edits](/questions/tagged/serial-edits), and [serial-voting](/questions/tagged/serial-voting).
- Questions about what sort of questions are on-topic or off-topic should be tagged [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic).
- Questions about when it is acceptable or desirable to upvote or downvote a post should be tagged [voting](/questions/tagged/voting), [up-votes](/questions/tagged/up-votes), and/or [down-votes](/questions/tagged/down-votes).

Could we burninate these nonexistent community standards?

Comment: Better title: There are [community-standards] here!?